# HttpClient returning special characters but nothing readable

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, httpclient

I am trying to download a webpage using async and await and HttpClient, but am getting only a string full of special characters... Code is like..

```
static async void DownloadPageAsync(string url)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    var str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

}
```

and url is

```
url = @"http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/live_index_watch.htm";
```

When i did

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
                                 "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; 
                                  WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
```

in place of those four DefaultRequestHeaders, I got a 403 error, but this is nse site and is free for all. Please help friends get me correct response.. 
regards

Srivastava

Comment: have you tried `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` instead of using a stream?

Comment: yes, tried that too, but was getting same thing, questionmark inside diamonds, \b\0\0\0 etc and whole lot of unreadable characters..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
```

With this you tell the server that you allow it to compress the response [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)/[deflate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE). So the response is actually compressed which explains why you get the kind of response text you get.

If you want plain text, you shouldn’t add the header, so the server won’t compress the response. If you remove above line, you get a normal HTML response text.

Alternatively, you can of course keep that header in and decompress the response using [GZipStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) after receiving it. That would work like this:

```
using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
using (var deflateStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(deflateStream))
{
    var str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Ideally, you should check the value of `response.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Encoding")` to make sure that the encoding is `gzip`. Since you also accepted `deflate` as a possible encoding, you could then use [DeflateStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) to decode that; or don’t decode anything in case the Content-Encoding header is missing.

Comment: in recent .Net version, check `response.Content.Headers.ContentEncoding`