# C# UWP - HttpClient issue with response \u001... can't deserialize

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I am trying to call a REST API from HttpClient class in C# for my UWP app.
Usually, I use the HttpConnection class to get content.

Here is my Get method :

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri, string accessToken = null, bool forceRefresh = false) {
        T result = default;

        // The responseCache is a simple store of past responses to avoid unnecessary requests for the same resource.
        // Feel free to remove it or extend this request logic as appropraite for your app.
        if (forceRefresh || !_responseCache.ContainsKey(uri)) {
            SetAuthorizationHeader(accessToken);
            var json = await _client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            result = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json));

            if (_responseCache.ContainsKey(uri)) _responseCache[uri] = result;
            else _responseCache.Add(uri, result);
        } else {
            result = (T)_responseCache[uri];
        }

        return result;
    }
```

It automatically parses the response to the corresponding object type.
The problem is that when I start my app, it stops because of a deserialization failure :

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0

It is because json variable receive this value (full payload) :

```
\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0003��r�F����)\u0010�\vτ�E��bDǙr��)�%U���p0@\u0012�P�\b6\0J�t�.�n���^lv\u0002H ��\u0004Apo��@��-K�ZH\0L��˽�_\u007f3�'��a\u001c9ˣ���t�G�a�����+oiϢ�\u001c����?w�w\u0017�\u001d?Z�|�[�n\u001eOO^\u000f�\u001e\u007f힝���?ź���-\u007f�qV^+�o\u05ee\u0015���\u001bם��\a��wΪ��<ײ����Ik߹c\u001a\u0013��r\u0003;���W�\u000f��G\0cp�+g��\v��7\u001fe\u007f<�\u000e��n,\u0003��\r���_��ŧ\u000f��O����ۇ��\u0016\u001c���6��\\��p\u001dL������+'���7��/�Uh��W\vﶽis����g?Ӻ�\u0013���f\u007f(���D9�\u0003���\u001d�ux�\u0016�/>�����]z��݃t��V\u0005�v��l\u0014���\u001e��짶\u0017^�p�a�\u007f\b'�\t�z�zŞ��f��;[�\f�������&υ�e��\u001fOm�^{��f\u001e,|g\u001d:ު�a\a�Bv\u001e<��Z9�V}aP\b2=v��\u000e0zf&d���_O)~�S;z�/\u001e����\v۹�k��zA#;��a\u001dM\\?\u009d��6pB{f-o�y%�|���d\n��妝ߖvz{�C�&s������}�C�u<�\u001a��x�\u001c�ѥ��\u0014���#�F�9@{PL~�\u0015��\b�\u0003H�þ�\u001f�d��\u0013��Ax%\u001f-`&��o���٬���$���\u007f��(��[�aER�l]{\u001e�U����\u0013\u0004\u001b��\v��Y�\u0014�6\u007f��6��l�>����\u0014k�XA�\\�l\u001b��rOm�M�h�[��5�\vW{j�?e��u�4�\u0010��9���\u001cI\u0016>M�#��vpm��\r��1�-�\u0015�03aj��o_\"z0��G��I� �\\�\u0001>,�pg!�����ī�Z���u�e�����}\u0e72\u001e�\u007f^�x�3=��>B��|�9�g��8�U0Qa]�L��\u0011}��yu�\u001f\u0006��u{�l��U�r�W\u0005&&���?�\f��>�N�\u0015>>�0\u0018���.�%�o��\u0019ΐ��@>\0�2�b�t�q����k+�N�b�_[��3�D��4�\u0002��W�^=]�V������Ѧ�X+}_�\u0017��i\u001fg\u0014OV�\u0006\u001fEo�0��v���%|os=k�t]R9>����\u0019I�%�Yk�U�\u000e?��\fn\u001d�\u000eBo�����IV+/t.�E�o�\u0015'����\u007f\u0004�ja��r�\u007f�\v%t\u0016\u000e�~ mHo\b�\u0006ac��X\v\u0006\t�Wj�ۮ\r�'�+�՞�Y�q��\u05ee��8�\n�黎oC.��Y!����t;-�����Τ?����?r�^�\u001f�mu��۝����(}�z\u0013\\���\av���#g�\u0017~� N\u001ftI_rY���A\aׂ���T&��IQe��k��\u0012�{Dw�'�\u001d�����[{\r\u001f\u0002٥I��<��6��B�\u001c��6+v\u0015;ɟ�\u0010�����\u001f��A&{j�ؗ01��V0�'(�k�oxT{\r����E\u0018�\u007f��K�I�\u038d#?����ip\u001cW\u0014\u000f���}�'�+�ؒ�%o\a,�\u0016E�N`�]��kom��qɧ�Yث��TQ���3vH0���\tfi&�7\u000f���`��W�1A0����م_�ό\u001e�[2�;'p��\u000f���f�:\v~E��%���P��ŋ-�ji_Z\u001b7���O��\u0015����u\u0014\u007f���9\u001aw���qrD���t�?�������?��r&��\u0019\u0012�����o��'�{��g���J�U\u0001#l�h�\u0002�\u0015\rTH1P�\u0006�3x%��@�<�k�B2�\u001f\u0010*l��\n��\u001f�}m�����?\u0018�\u0014/�x��m2�� ���=0Ö��\u001b:h�q\u0011�΄\u0016H�\\\u000f�'t渰B�B�.tf� C�K�5tV��C�I�<t��\0Dg�BL\"\u001cRfI\u0003G�\u001c\tPI�\u001d\u00118�Y\u0012b\u0014�%\u0011T���!\u0016���p��\u0001\a��,\u00132�xN�qo���2��\b�Dg�\u0004&,\t#�ds�җs�-_�J3ڲ��b\u001b��! �Λ\u0010��-#ZD\axt��Ggt\0���&@A:+*0���D:�C@#���\u0011��@Ȁ�ΐ\u0012/�<+�&\u0006��fg�\u001dO�q\u0005�dN\u0006椗=�\b�LƯ���أ&��`�fh{��\n�5AT\u0005�\u000e����J%��;���8U�f���\u0006P\u0001Y\"\u0002T@��\u00150���\u0001�:\u0018�J��\b�|\u0019n\u0005�����\u0003�.�AR\t��\u0003��]Χ�Y�����D��y�fe��]˿��}�r��\\4�ET��%7qi�K\u0015��X5Ī)�I\vi���)�\u0011�ѪTl}�2�*s]�W��{����)�����\\l֟��\u0002\u000fH\\�D&0,6�¿�8&�n�{o�7N\0KP�Y\u0018*\u0004�\u0001<ɱ�g�>�\u001b����A��+d�Ue��yW�:\u0012�*� b]������\u001a�s�z�R�R+2�U�I�J�H�V�#>�*��a[�\u0016\u0014dk�!2���I���a3�RC\n�Uj�ͳJ�\bhV�\u001f\u0005�*5� YU\f�8V���&�K�J\u001di\u0018V�%�cR}C��\u001b\u0001;\0\\��Y�/)�*u��W[\f��U�-\u001e�*���V�ƘԪ�\b�Y���\u0010�RGR^U�|8ZUz\u0018���Ԏ�T�:V�Tf�3ju���Ѥߟ\fz\u00158Uw��DK�T�q�\u0004I�T�� ��bo�U���\u0006V�RUUܕQU�ݍP��V�S�\u0010�N�=uk�T\\������\u0002��\u0017�N�b�q�3\u001evƼ\boK���ɻ��_�\u007fo˰�O�\r��veM�g5��\u0001L\r`j\0�K�&���'�\u0002U�ʒX\u05f5\u0018@�!���]���4v|\u0018\u0014\u001f*k�F�~M\u001e���O20|֓\b�\u0001�D�\u0010T'�\"B9�:5�IlH�\r��Pڰ�/\nb<�\u001c=s�c2�\t\u0011�\u0011��܊M�$��%\u0019\v!gI\u001ch�JbBLT�P\b��).�Н�\u007fBا\u001eGv�\u0006&��Di�W��z8D�=�١x�pc��ave�\a\u0005\u0017��jG�\"�\u001d��:\u0010�H܈�F�NI3\u0012\vj���\u001c�[$v_\u0004V$ޤ�\"��\u0012���:���B�\u0006m\u0011��Ss0\u0019@��a\u0005\u0016\u000153�I7�\u00162�`=ߎ�&������j�&�:{\u0003����Ӣ���v*�����Q�\u0017\n�g�Y\u007f���\u0017��A��\u001d\u001f\u000f*5c뜞��x:=\u001d�O\u007f��\u0002|H�t�6�Z���\t\u0016^�I�y8*�h��܆54��a\r\rkx�a�4W \u000e�\u001d����\u007f\u0019�e�ȶz�Mho`w'�e{\u0003�\u0004��0\u0002o\u0013\u0018o��k�;�@�\u000f[\u000e�~u�F\u0018�E�ԉ��Ύ�K�\\��N\u001e�Q�\\�H��\u0010�W�<H���\f�]�pjMt�\u0014\u001c��\v�f�Ya2�2\u001f�\u0012�\u0017\u0005��yaS\u000e�\u000f\u0001��Y���-m���P�Q�\u0010@�EQ>��\v�rD�\u0004\u0013�\u0016���h�Etn\u001c�\u0010���,I��Δ�\u0004�وދ���\u001c�8�\u0381���<1���\u0003���H��Ό���L\u000f�RtG�OTtN$\\EgV���e��ңgN�*�\u001e\u0011]\u0019dФ��tD`�K��fL�\u0018K\u0005�]�;*H�Vڡ\u0011�@]\u0006<6�>\u0019J{�T�\u001bG�\r�i:\u0016o'��t��!`_���ذbڨ'�\u0017���4\u0019�w������0O���8��:9�n���t���ɷ�Y�^\0[�9i�W��M��\r[i�J�V\u001a����Ja\u0012,6\u0005K�\f]���\u0017K�YA�w�Z-��N�`�^{~h@�7�>l�g�ӓ�\u001c]�h�O�X|$90�\u0012��p�\t\b\u001f\u0006\u0016��zȌ���A\r�J1�(\r���\u0004�\"�-PJ+қ��D�c%(��\u001d8*k�\u001d4r�Dz�$4�\u001f9:>��\u0014��k×V|@�\u001e8A%Dv-�\v �7\u0018���s/\u001c%Uث�!w�DU\u000e�\am�/ޙ�}&N\u0016�s\v�d�K�F��\u00045{��a;W�I�Ӌ��@/a��w�O_P\a����\b\u0002s.M����g��\u0003�\u000e�u��9�\f��Q����_\u001a�C\u0019Ðm\u001d?\u0018Oj�\b�/x�\f<9\u0005��\u0017(�`��\u0002�P!�6�8�\u0004M�M��{�b>�T\u001b�\v��x<�-���0���~6��=�*�\u0018����������E�!q��[��&�n��&�n�~�g�B\u000e��3w����\u007f�\u001bv��NE�����s\u001b��K�\u0001�p��AtG\u0004��֝\u0015��\\L�?��u\u0004�&RD�\u0010&�\u001eP8���\nC�\0]��\u001b�+\f�Bu�\u0017f���'\t�\u0015>����\u0004�*@!L\u0011�kl�k\u00014.�Ѽ�\u0002�\u0002@aC\u0011�+l��{�\u0005A��p�\b�\u00156\u0014\v��6hk�\u0015\u0016� ~���\n\u001f���\n#�E�\n7R\u0010��c�76\u0012P�P�\u0001�\u0019\u001e&P�S\u0002\u0003�\u001d&:PȣC\u0004�\a\tNP����W�\u001d\u000e1(��a�\u0084\u0004;(|*��\u001f�-���Q�\u0003�\u007fW\u0003\u0010Ǔn�\u001b��&��:���.�\0 :�\u0003wY�/\u000f�\u001e�(��u%~��n��e�\n��\u0018�S\u001c�i6U��{��k���/�[���r�V�yn�\\T\u0006,\\�\v-��o�p|�7G�\u0001�_�AE�t��\u0002�Ѐ�\voqc�o\u007f�n\u05ee�\u0003�P>�A\u0015\r�hPE�*�\u001a�B9�\u0015���F+g\u0011��=}���\u001d�@B#���/�ȉ��2)��[\u001d�H�\u001dQ�D^��I�\u001d��D�\f�J��\t�Dވ�K\u0014n,�����K^��L�>$hB��g\u0013�\a\r����щ�\u000f\r����_Y�P���\u0012E�P�M��n�\u0003\u0014��\u0010\u0014\u001e�Ɠ�\u0010dD�\u001f\v!��_7J��*\u0013T���R�\av\0LQ�dT���C\v*�nؤ\"�N�*�~��Bu�IU\u0003\u0011_@�O\tiE��S�A���C��p��Eޅ�X\u0014��J5\u0013��s�?5;�N\u007fү�,��~5d1�t�kmҠ�9�a\u0016�\u0013�O%Ŷ�ک�B!V\u0001[���[<��\u001a\u0016�ÐE`�w�>��,\\��W��5\u007fh-=���\u0011���x4�8\u0018�B0�\u001eo��bq\u000f��\b�\"`�\u001638\u0005���B\u001f�\u0006�:aXq���nhFC3\u001a��Ќ�N3�Nt\u0005�1�'� ��sF��O߱I����\u000f6��HxC�O\u00049C�\u0004<�\u0006��C�C\u0006?��\bD�B\u0002B�v�8D�S��ק@#�nȀ��\f\u0013��;a�\u0012�\u001b\u00052ѻa�\u0013�\u0013Ay�ތ\u0002���(�=���\u0001\u0015���t�[�����\0��\u0011\"\u0016�))h��R����QA\u0017�'\u001ez�{P\u0002\u0018�+&�ѻ�W��H��ގ��Do{8<�?\u0006|H��\"A5z��5&C\u0006l:Ǔ�xҫ��Cwҁ�Uݔ�\u0014kLX��D�m\u00101�\u0005l����m*��ZqRIt��\u0013�d\u0005��m8���8�\u0005�h�{`[o3ZS���}���w�(8Y�־��^��Іj\u0013�\u0010�R���i\r�i\0M\u0003h\u001a@��\u0001�vb,��d�d�kGsi\u0018�\u0019�R\u0013���\a����Ebda*\u0004#;\u0011�\u0017�\u0010\v���ȴE6��,�\u0017*_��i���C@Td\u0013$�\"\v�0\u0014�\r6<Q��R\u0013�\u0005:.�mH8�l�\u000eHd\v\n2\"�� \u0011ن��hm� �lAC?d\u001f\"�!\u001bQ�\u000eٍ\u0016t�~$�CeC�6d3D�!���\f�\u000e�b����B���\u0016�\u000f-���\u000eH*ds\u0002D!�а\t٧\n���N�-s�\u001a_�~�Bm�f��,q9�BHz���n��*�\u0012�\f_(�Ĩ�1��\a�yԃ\u0012�pj҈R��1D�ڎ�AҪ\0\u001e�\u0006�٧�Z�N\u001f�\u007f\b�a\u0013�\u0004c4{O��=�\u0006��o�I�s\u0002h��:�\u0003{A�7s�Y�\u0019S\0���A��^��7\u0011�|Gq�WK��ڸ�,�R˄o-}���\b^ƃq?9�mE\"�\u0016���ޙ�'\u001f�\"\u0011�K���[�!n�\u0005v�ޞ\aNE�P�Ԇ>4��\u000f\r}x��|�+\u0010�\vVn\b�q�lύ�q�-��/���Ѷ\u0016a����Ň\u001f��q�\u0016!����Uh\u0004�&0N�i�@F\u0015��^\u001fW�u���F�\b[h�hх�\u0014\t_h�q\u0011�Ƅ\fch�0Q�Ƃ\u0004gh���\b\akh�)�F�\u00152�(q�D\u001c%6ؘCcE�:4VظCcC�<4N\u0014�CcE�>ʭ��Ɔ\u0004�h�h0�ƌ\u0010�h\u001cIq�Ɠ\u0002�h�����\u0010\u000f�h\f(��\u0012\u0013�h,�1�Ƈ\u0004�h�Hq���p�Ds\0��DcD�N4^U�\t\u0014`\fZ&�\u001b\u0002\u001b��&f�Z�\u0014���~V���'�i\a6\r9\u0006�Z�D=�z\be�֮\u0018e��n(E�W\u0001��X\u001d�؆�\u0017Ql�@\u0015�\u0010\u0004;��Cr��5�%��\u0018Z�����H��g^\b�\u001f\u000e��N��(\u0004�8��:9�n�Y\u007fz�突u��k9���i�\a�����w�\n:�y�e_]�m�q\rXi�J\u0003V\u001a�����0�\u0015(�wNh���C��2\0xri��j�U�y�\rL���\u001b�\t���.�L��p\u001dL�mk�\u000fHכ�+�F��m@��\u0019�>\ba�B�l>�3JQ��0S\"B\u001cq\u0004��G{ϷB�\u000f��\"���\u001f{�\u001fj\u001f<\u0012�`\a�K*�\"\u0019�`�\f��\0\a&�O\u0017�*\u000eJ`J�1��\u001cnPh]�ޗ��\u00193�}k�eY���,&\u0011�\0;�g�\u0014Y?��\u000e��c��\u0011��RD���\u0012�x!袅��9��\u0016���W\u0012���ZP��<\u0012��L���3B\u001a���\u000e{���R�-�n?ͭ���իWO\u05f6�L'�8Ȯ}��rpv���7��L���\u0002q\a\t&J�]3aҠ�\u0019\u001c.�fn�\u00114S%ɛ�{��\u000e\u000f��\a�2\v�MXq�mǠ\n��G\u0092���a� ه��Yg!8&���\u001f��\u0010�?�&��\u000eT/I\u0006�}vp(<}��\u0018�\\!\u0010\u001e�4�\u0011��fm=��z��7lW�hk�/�\v���O\u007f`\u000e���^��>�r7��\u001b)�uVN�D�iY���k���]�Ӛ��Iz���Iz_zҫ��\n���x�4��8����z���#�K�c��-Y?\u001f\u0006h��hO\u001f�v�c:����#��\u0015˚HѱB�(IV8�.�W\u0018\"��\ne��Ya@�B+�0Ci�<IF�����\u0015&8\t�B�}?�\u000e�56ȋ�5.�q��\u0002;�V�P��\n\u001b�l\\aA��]�B��+l(�t�\rZ���P&�,��'fW���E�W�0\"\f�\u0015n���\u008fbA�҆j1��\f/�W�S��\n;�x_!��x]�A\u0012�+|HY���ph@a�O\n\u0014&$�@�S�#��NѰ�sg�\u001d�t@�\u0011�\u0010��]\u0013p�H\u001c����Q y�z�\0G\u0010�\u0001���d]\u0015�X�\u0011����\n�:�.N/W�\r:�Z\u0015\u0018\u0004�Z¡\u0010G,�h\u0016�;\v{\u0015�e������3�(Z�(z�\u001e�\u0013�\u0019\u001d�N\a�'�M���\u0001H����]�E�Y\r�h�E\u0003-\u001ah�\u0017�\u0016�\t��,ޥ����_I\u001f\u001f:\u001aQ�����Zk��I\u001f�EćJ��]\u001e��HD20|\u0010�\b�q�D�\u0010\u0018\"�\"�\u0010�:5�HlH\u0019\u0004��`};�5\"b��&&\u0010��3\u0017:\0!�\u0010�\aq\u0018�m\u0017�Gs\\�tI��C2\u0016B��8в�Ą\u0018=�\u0010,�ߠ\u0012�A\u0001\u001eҳE��_\u001e\b9v\u0010�Ö�K\v��w�\b����^���\u000e\u008d�]\u0016 _)8EDE\u0002�\u0017\tqH�ց�C�F�\u001b\u0012uJܐXPӆ��P�!��\"�!�&E\r�\a5i�ww����\u001bN\a��\f'н�ߩ\u0004\u001az=�n�\u0016,�$l&\u0010u����!N�n8Ҭ�7g�O�>�\f��t�*�?����\u001eC��\u0002\u0019�\u0010�IԖ��q�B���\u0001��\u0001NprE�0��'\u0014@�W�\u0019�\a��\u0003�ng�\u001bv�\u000e\u0016[���ɻ������ɢ\u001c=�+�Z/�ܫD|V�\u001e\u001a�Р�\u0006=��Ѓ8���\a�+{u�@��*��x������SJ\u0016���qX\u0004��`\u0011�.}Y�ҋ�\u000e�\"\"?\n\u0016\u0011\t\u0013��H�0,\"�\"c\u0011�:=��l�YD|3\u1cc8H��E�.�,\"5!c\u0011�0(YD�B�\"\"\u0017R\u0016�ǁ�2H��A�@Hv!��HޠHYDtI�u\tlQ)R\rD2�\u0003��t8�`\u0011���XD26V\\\u001b\u0006���Vx��\u0010J�A1���^Q��\u000f�\"�\u0011\u0011��H�`,\"r#c\u0011\u008d&�\u001f ]vz\u0016\u0011_q\b.��[1x���γ\u001c�(�\r�F��XD4Tb\u0016\u0011yг����\"�.�f�0�\u0015=�<���\"���{㉙=��?�(z�ߋ\u0010X\u0004;)h,�(V��!\u001e^\u0005\u0016��a\u0011M�%�2\a\rs�]�g� t�\u000f�~�s<��ꚭ\u0004�C���\v[ �\u0011\b;X����>����?4���\u000f\u007f!����\n��͵�_Ŭa��fe\u001b\v�\u000fm���{a\u001eE�ǔ��1�C���\u001cbYz�\u0010�\u001c�8�v��!�%�\r��!pC�DD\u001bbqj�\u0010�����6�F\r�,1i�L�@C�A�\u0019�A�a�؄�2�&��!\u001d\u0005!c�=��\u001d���V;�L(�\u001d����u�^\u001fJ��;\"�'f���\v�ס�BvG\u0013����ї9�V$d!�>\u0010X�͈��x�IA<\nV�\u001d��Br�\u000f\u0004\u0015b�/�\u0014bkR�\u0010[P\u0013�䶮\f\u0014��Qg28\u00167�-\u0005\nl�\u0012�`B}�p��N@u�.J�`��\t��\u001e\u001d�$��4!R�\0\u0013L��<+4��\u0003�U\b\r�xۛ{+\\\\�~ ��\u007f\u001a�7\vj*\u001a�+\u001aT\u0015\f�\u0005~\u00010ax<\u001e�7�==y{\u007f�~�.�;~�~�x�X�<�}��}z�xvrU\u0006\u0013|�Z�\\͐{R\u0003\u0013\u001a����\u0006&��`Bn~+n��^��\"�=\a�����է�X{\u001b߸���o�\u0006\u0003\f�\u0003Ui��+g��O;�¶d@�\u0010XX����1\u0018C���\u0018bYz�\u0010�\u001c�1�v��!�%c\f��!\u0018C�D�\u0018bqj�\u0010��2��6�f\f�,1c�L�\u0018C�A�\u0018�A�1�؄�1�&��!\u001d\u0005!c�=�\u0019C2\u0010ZƐ3�`\f�T�2���A�\u0018���3���P�!��\t\u0019Cz��\u0019ClE�\u0018b�\u00031�،�1��\u0018\rc�\u001d�\u0019Cr�\u000f�\u0018b�/�\u0018bkR�\u0010[P3�䶮�\u0018\u0006�n�5P\u001at&f����1t�)��\u001cj\u0019\u0003��\u0010o�\0\u000f\u001cO\u0006{\u0017-D�ٛ1H*{0\u0006I�6c��*0\u0006�]��؞���\f��3��寜�Uk��Zz�C�G)��\u0011��-�?�s\u0002g�N�\0���z3�hI�\u0011\b\b�[۫Y�yE\u0001��_-�Kkㆳ�++\u0013��4\u0005\n��`<\u001a�M^\u000f#\u0014($\u001bH����>�CZY�lW�#1��\u0004��\u0003�9\r=h�AC\u000f\u001az�W�\a��V�\a\u001f�O�{\u07fb�-�¾�2~`��XW��\u0006\b\u0002l\u0019��/\u0010�\u0002q�F\u0001\u0005 H�\t��\u00010\u0001�9\u001c%`n\u0004����1\u0002�~\u0010D���\b\u0001�&\a\u0004̄�\u000fD7\u0010:\u001e`��t�{\u0010�\u0001nA�\u0006�!\u0010�\u0001�AM\u0006�\a%\u0018H�@�\u0005�\u00055\u0016��AL\u0005\u0004\u000f\u0012(\u0010�'b&�_\u0017�H�\u000f�\0D�Y\u001d\f\b�[��\a$��\08�9��\0�|(\u0018���X@vs\u0011�\0f@N\u0002��|(\u0010�̾\f\a`δ\u0018�9�S��~�\0\u0001���a\u0013f\u0006\u0001�РWi\u0017��p���[Pn��$G\u0013h���*\u0012jv.�a,�3���>\b�x<u�O`\u0003�\0\0�6hf\tDjg\u0005Y�\u001c�\u001b;I\u001fX����>ً�\u0005Ѕ�d\u0013��{�Ƒ���|��\\Zn�-X�!\u0017C�:���I���w���v��eAd�\u0004�ܕ~-\u0004�r��A�������\bj\b��*�Y��˰,���^�\u0001\u00154ޛq\u001cpc�9+�\u001d�k�W�v[�\u0003�S���I����I��BI�0�I;\u001e@��q���6~�W��~X�>\u0010_�7\u0002(\u00178�玕M��\u0001�l�\u0011��\u001e~��D��~�r������L�,�g⇈��\u000fQ�Ϥ��~�A��G�\u000ev��D�S~nA\u0017�s\a��?\u001d\0]��,�\u0013~fA\u0018�'# ���\u0003q�\u001f\r�6�\u0017,(���$�f���@\u001a���'���P�>��\ts������̈$�g�\a\n��\u0015Q���V4�>ӧN�K|�@�y}�<�\u0019���̀:͏n�\na��2;�N�5�\a�����7�#�#��H��L���;�t�^�\u000fC�;�/h�\u0011�\u0017��n�\u000f:U��q������5{\u000f���gW�ye����\a����\u001f6\u001f���u�� �RدyN��7i\u007f��7i�KO�5�[!���a�v����q!�\u000f��G^Я9���'�A]��:��ەv�+��H�\u001f4\v�k�\r.�\u0012%�E\u001bڈ�膔�\u0017eqC��:Y�_4\u008c���$9\u007f�\u0004?�/:�$�EU��_停��,0�~�~���\u0017=(���\av�_��z��w\u00051�Gyw�H��a\u0010D�\u001a\u000f�̿��\f��r��\u000f(\u0017�M\u001fJ���\u0011P\r�(�/Z���E3v+c\a���-Q�_t\u008b��ʔ�\u007f�\v3�/j�7\u0017b�_4 ���&��\u007f��p\0��O\0�\u000e$\b�hR�\u0001�-x\u0006\u0011\u0003�Mz�J\v�;��\u007fKW�.,��AK�I'�\u0011�eA\u007fa,� @�Ȯ\u0014�Dj��>\u0005�\n\u001c`��A����Í\r�Nr)a\u007f�[˿ao&�o�H\u0002�\u001e\u07b5\u0001\u001e\u0002-~��\"�Y���pdv\u0006�a�M��>-~?=��s�؄\u0018r�ٍm�2֊h���\n4T��\u0002\r\u0015x�T�8�\u0015�������,\u001f���?�^\u0018�\u007f�!��\r��^\u0018P�vy�Ǜ\u0012����\u000e���]��%GH\u001d�\u00143v�Z�L\v�\u000e@\u0010$#\u0004�:\u0011��\u0017���\u0005�C�F\u0002�0!\rH=pA@*K�\0R}��?\u0015�J�SA��?'�����q��������<M����g��c��\u0017�@�D?;x�0�(�����d}�\b?w�+=�L�s\u0003 \v�S\u0017��^\u0018\rE\\/�,��>5�\f�SQ�|>����\v�\u000fj*�j\u0013\u0005���\\�/Lч����Q$�8Q��ݬ���w\u0006-��\u001a��Z���B�ޝt;b�^l�\u0003�y@r<�����I/[ο[�·Q7rW=\u007f��]��k��5�d��c���Go��:�k��\u0016�G��������u���\u0002r�YhC�a��]���'��\u03825\u0003�W���\f|V\f<�nYپ�Y���\u001f�!떼�~\u0010bw�H�[�,��t)z^�{��1G�^G�h��Å+5�����\u007fj�?\u007fS)[�\u001e�D�M��D�M��ңuib+$��ߍ����}+�;��O��\u07bb4�\u001fx;Y��lK\u0012��:�A�_q�J!��\u001eQ��\u0019Ю��|�\u0012�L\u00107@�t����\u00023>�TI��L\u001e?<\u0017n\u000e��8�\u001eEt�WGN����yᰑs�L�\"6�ԱS��qc��8Ef.\u001c:Ad.��%��Y!ht��������\u0013��\tiZ��A�\u05f6��\u0014QV�y�E�&eR��`\u0006��\u001b\a1'ϤIbr�JR����B��\u0013?#ϴI\"r�.�����V\u0017Z���;k%��o\u0016��@��u�/&�i�zH�G��&\r�wI��Q�\vȕO�5\u001fW��\u0016��\u0012\u0015��\u0011R6���m�qȴŎ�8���\u000e!��\u0016_(�\u000eBX�\r��\u001f�y���#����\r���h�Ut�9=y{\u007f�~�.�;~�~�x�X�<�}����t�=�t�O~��6�!��`v{������\u0001x��C,�6�\u007fZ\u0013�7�x\u0013�7��K���3\\q�9̙����\b�M`��|����x�����6Q\taO��o\u001b�?e�\u0011'\"�\u001fd��\\�D\n�\u0015�D�\u00896FW\u0018\"��\ne�`]a@��+�0�v�<I���\u000f�\u0015&8+�\u0015�\u0014q��\u00069�\u05f8`\u0006�\u001a\v�>6\n\u001b��^a���+,\b\u001a�(\\(�|�\rE'{�\rZ���P�����W���E��\ny�\u0011ד���--��\u0003iz��=\n7R\u0006��ht����u�0��\u0003\nqJN���\u0004\u0006\ny�7\n\u000f\u0012���!�~��;\u001cTP���\u0005�\t\tfP�T�\u0013-������\u000et�����yCwb�ž�E��W䛃�\u001b~&�\vo��S\u000f<���J ��vC\u0011�V\u0005&a�X+�\u0019������Mа\t��W��5\u007f��_Y\r@�ֳN9w��?���\vq\v'j̯�\u0016�\u001d\u007f�\u0019(�諩�������l�VG-|;\bg�ry\u0017dQ|N�+\u001a^���W�ExEqz+�����\u0019\u001f�^Ls�\"�>Q�D�H�&\u0012\\\u0010\u0017G���,\"�9\b�H�p)D*K� Ruj��\u001a\u0011��T��<�&d�!��PV�'_KRUB��\r9\v\u0002Ԑ\u001f\u0002rE@�R\u0010B�t\u001cD�!է�\v�\u0005![ȆAP/ ]��\u0003�*\b牠v�8\bR��\u001b\nQ\u001dAq@� \t�[\u0019���8  -D�\u0005E't����\u0003Ѓԋ\0\u001d��T� 5��\u0006��!�Ajvp\\�:���ԁ\u0012\u0014d�s��\u0004F\t�=\u0010�W�\u0004\u0010�\u000f���JJ��\u0003<j<����S�a�B\u0004���\"5��J�\u0016\u001c�B\u0015�@��X�Ѐ\u0001ga�\u0002֝��hA\u000f\u0006��9c\u0003��C�\u001f�yс�9�w��C~Ǳ��E�\u000eG\u001fg7W'�ߝ\u007f�3_��/�y\u0017.4�\u007f�^W�\0�Û���������_z�/�l���gg\u0005�2\u0002�[Ͽ\r\f��q\u000f{�\u0018�X��+�۬�?\u0003\u0006\u00106\u001b��\u0002����\u0001�\u0016\u0012\n\u0010\u0004�(��@\v\0\u0004#��_Pč�\u0005a��_��\f�\u0005Y��_�Ǐ��[\u0004%�\u0017\u0004)���<r�_Pǌ�\a���\v�\u0014!� ����\u001c����N�ڋ\aO\u0010���hY}��\u0010���\u001d\u007f�\u007fa\0D��B��\u0017�S�H>\u007f���x�\u0004/�\u0017D)3x�\u00063~�n\u001f�\u0018%��k\u0015�\b�$��x9)��\b>���\u0005S��]\u0010'\t�ś�R�nvZ�\u0005�������\u0013?y$����l=�ޖ=�8j��I�\u0002?\u001bF�X]��]\u0013u��naz�Q!G�a��y��ԭ鈏�\u0011\u001f�W}\u0016��=\u007f��;��|�\u0010\u0019E>�?�K\r�ۻY`�w\u0015w��\u001f���M>���M>���qyf+���V����}�㭌�W�k{uj/\u001d�'k�F����6\u0016�\u000f�~>Z�zn����>+>�\t���\u001f�gZHA� H\u0014�\v\u000e�A�`�\u0014�\v��A� L\u0016�\v\u001e�A� K\u0012�\v��A�x��\u0004� EP^�G\u000e�\v�Ay����rA�\"(\u0017䱃���c\a�:EP.\u001e<AP.ˣ\u0005�\u0013C\u0010�\u0017�w���0\0��\\p!\r�\v�)vP�?YDA�`�\u0017�\v��A�`�\u0019�K�\u000fbP.h�\u0004���\f�\u0005��\u0005�)~P.��\u0004���Z9(\u001fM�/~\u007f\b��\u0004��\v��!R�֖����)4���j�]��l\u0018��r��w\r��*�\u0005�F�����A��>�ڶY��\u000e��\f����5ĵ�\u001f����\u0002��&(�\fʗ�bÚ�E9I�������3��7\u001c�CE��du�O����/�.�\f�j\u0003�UZ�\u0017\u001e���Mn���Mn��s�´V\b��\\�ޭm�_�v��VN�X�\u0013$\u0011���\v\u001b�+\u001b��\u0012��ҩ\u0014'-/NРZoeM\"���s5�����&��\u0005)\u001e�r��8W%\vƹ\u0001f*�5I\"q.����7\u0004J\u0018��(�pQ\u001b9\u0006\u0017�13��!#\a�\\�\"����ѷp�ع7��\b���&H�\v�hqwv>\b�n��\u000f��C'J��\u0005i�-ޒ���p���mlsE�X�{`f���\u00051���$ivz�(�lnr�\u001c�;��\\�$�N��j�5tF\u001fN���`8�W��\a�\rl�m�\u0018_�-\u0013$!�[h��K|���^v�x���Bb��:\u0011�\u0012Y�L����$']B\u00060wmּ��r\u0003�k\u000fN�,~\u001b��{��(�(�hyA\u0016WkS�8��Z�-\u0019͝\u00138s�u�\a\u058cd���\u000e�~\u0014��\u0013؄0D\u0005�\u0010~��/ٺ�Y�-�\t�Z���\u001b���aO��[�7������ɇ���R���Cx�fQ\a�\u001dV��֤�M�ݤ�M���Sn�Ĩm��ܮ]۰W���������/\a��q��[:�6U�-;\u0011��!V\u001e.+#G�\u0001]J.{�\u0006�<Mv.�\u0010��\t�ή��7I�.\u001f?�����.����\u0002{gW�e!\t��Ѡg�\u0005A�u��\"I�\u0015��\b�6x��l�L�Y����V�\tŅa/|�W��jM\u0018�\u001e\u0010U�/��f��\u001f�ή��Eו]a�\b\u0003�\u0013F�\u0005d;TD �Ƿ\u001b&-�=h���Cڧ]q�\u001d\u0010'ȃ% \v�\t\rd�}*��\n}`���=�^�g;���Ȅ�\u001b�\r�9f}e�#h۞��߉7Hé�\u001eJuv�\u0010�j;\u0002\tI�\u0002�@B\u0013G�#�\u0530YQ����շn\u007f���{�q�x48���������ta�+6r�w8�����Nf�`^i�}��\u001a$� �\u0006I4H�#��)��$΅\u0019����\u001b\u0006%�|�u���)2�(9��hB!��&T�DpBeEK'T�HxB%��'T\u000ed�Be�I(T�$�Be��(T.8�B�LA)t>ȘBg��)t\u001eؠB�CA*T>بB�A�*T6\u0014�B�\u0013\u0010Њ\u0012\u001f4\\��P2�}y�ʈ\u0006X��8\u0001�b��=.\u00021\04j�\u0018�\u001d)�P\u0019R0\v�\u000f�V�*7<j�R��\u0016*?Ln��G\a\u0017*\u0013\u0012r�2\"E\u0017*�ñ\v�;>�P���\v�Qe|a�Ss\u0004��'����f��B{9�X���n�\u001bu�g�~�\n��V���O\u001e�봿\v�P��\u001e��\"�+��\"�\u001b�P�U@\u0018c�\u000e�<\u007f�\u001a\u0002�?\b\r�� \u0010i�E�3\u0012t;��g,�qVW����R\r'��6,p�\u0017\u0005�A,�\b���`%\u000f���$\f�H\f�\n\v�!P|!�\t�\u000e\a-h�C��,�\u0001v��\u0018w��}���\u0010���8?y�=�~����T����Nk��\n��\r�h\u0010F�0\u001a���\u0011�<�\u0015��\u0005ۙ\u0004�\u0003�lϿ��n���?�?�z�\u0013vؗ��>�ȴ�p� HD)\u0004\aZ8!\u0018!1\tA\u0011\u0017E\b�d\u0004B��\u0004\u000f�,\to\u0010��1�x��4\u0015\u0012\u0004)�BA\u001e�%\u0014�1\u0011B���\u001b\f\t�\u0014�@���\u0004�#��4$�SP\u0001��\t`�,��\0r'���P�~WⅽJ\u0014\n\u0003 *M\u0010\\H���}�݁(\u007f���\u0010\t&x!� J��\v6���t�H,��V��6I@/^NʶD����x�\u0014?�\u0017�I�w�f�Ԣ�3luGl+�\u0001l\u001d[�E\u0011d�%%\u0003Q8��*�A��`��=\u001bF��]��]\u0013v��n�z�Q!O7G%-�wJ�/�m�m2u�L]۟��Rk����}�\u0017�\u0017���Mj�����?\u0018\u0003�^8�\u0002\0
```

My app tries to call this endpoint : [https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos](https://api.github.com/users/%7Buser%7D/repos)

I already added thoses HTTP headers which gives same response string :

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36 Edg/100.0.1185.29");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6");
```

I also tried to adapt my code to do the same as in this official example : https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-customers-orders-database/blob/master/ContosoRepository/Rest/HttpHelper.cs

Thanks, Kevin

**EDIT:**

Example JSON payload : https://api.github.com/users/kevin-doolaeghe/repos

My model is (T-class) :

```
    public class GithubRepository {

    private int id;

    public int Id { get => id; }

    private string name;

    public string Name { get => name; }

    private string full_name;

    public string FullName { get => full_name; }

    private string description;

    public string Description { get => description; }

    private string html_url;

    public string Url { get => html_url; }

    private ICollection<string> topics;

    public ICollection<string> Topics { get => topics; }

    private int stargazers_count;

    public int StarsCount { get => stargazers_count; }

    private int watchers_count;

    public int WatchersCount { get => watchers_count; }

    private int forks_count;

    public int ForksCount { get => forks_count; }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full JSON payload from response, and what is the type of T (share the model)

Comment: Hello, I edited my post to include the full payload and the T-class

Comment: thanks! :) I keep looking at it too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things with your code:

1. The issue related to your question is that you are trying to compress the content, therefore you special or unusual characters like `\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\....etc` is a sign of content is compressed, and it is a result of this line:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, be");
```

For now, lets disable this line, and continue with next step.

2. Your JSON payload is array object, so your `T` needs to have be array like `T[]`

```
T[] result = default;
...
result = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T[]>(json));
```

and the method returning type should be `Task<T[]>`

3. Your model should be all the way with getters and setters like this:

```
public int Id { get ; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
...
...etc.
```

and delete all private property.

To test it:

```
var uri = "https://api.github.com/users/kevin-doolaeghe/repos";
var result = await GetAsync<GithubRepository>(uri);
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

It will work without issues.

Regarding step 1. issue with the gzip content compression issue, this has been already answered in by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899113/httpclient-returning-special-characters-but-nothing-readable).

Here is the result of the test I made:

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your complete answer with explanations :) Going to adapt my code and validate your answer. I should have know that gzip would compress data.. thanks

Comment: It works if I comment the Accept-Encoding header line! I can let T be object[] for instance